# Was AccessibilityService changed in Android Pie?

Tags: android, accessibilityservice

I have this AccessibilityService class working in Android Oreo (API 27) and before:

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.google.test.testaccessibility">

<application
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="TestAccessibility">
<service
    android:name=".TestAccessibility"
    android:permission="android.permission.BIND_ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityService" />
    </intent-filter>

    <meta-data
        android:name="android.accessibilityservice"
        android:resource="@xml/test_accessibility" />
</service>
</application>
```

**test_accessibility.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<accessibility-service xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:accessibilityEventTypes="typeViewTextChanged"
android:accessibilityFeedbackType="feedbackGeneric"
android:accessibilityFlags="flagDefault"
android:canRetrieveWindowContent="true"
android:notificationTimeout="10" />
```

**TestAccessibility.java**
    package com.google.test.testaccessibility;

```
import android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityService;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityEvent;

public class TestAccessibility extends AccessibilityService {
    @Override
    public void onAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent event) {
        Log.d("TestAccessibility", "onAccessibilityEvent");
    }

    @Override
    public void onInterrupt() {
        Log.d("TestAccessibility", "onInterrupt");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onServiceConnected() {
        Log.d("TestAccessibility", "onServiceConnected");
    }
}
```

It works and the method **onAccessibilityEvent** is called everytime a text is changed in any application but, when I run this code in an Android Pie (API 28) only the **onServiceConnected** one is called.
I suppose something has been changed in from API 27 to 28 but I can't find anything on the net.
Anyone can give me a clue?

Thank you!

Comment: This is a known bug in Android 9 and I have checked it based on user feedback that only Android One/Pixel devices had this issue, while working fine on OnePlus. You can check the link where I have opened the issue https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/117747909 is now fixed not sure if it is delivered to devices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a reported bug:

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/117747909

I'll try to update this response with the bug's answer.

Comment: The fix is in Android Q. We have a bug in P where we can lose track of the active window under certain conditions. It can be worked around in by setting FLAG_RETRIEVE_INTERACTIVE_WINDOWS, which tracks the active window through a separate code path.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing changed intentionally, and most services work.

Two things to try:
1) Codelab for accessibility service development: https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/developing-android-a11y-service/index.html

2) Removing the notificationTimeout

Comment: Thank you, 1) Is the tutorial I was following. and 2) was the first scenario I have compiled.

Trying some tweaks I've discovered that changing android:accessibilityEventTypes from "typeViewTextChanged" to "typeAllEventTypes" and filtering events by their type I've discovered that textchanged events are no longer received, instead of that I've only received selectionchanged ones.
So ¿Maybe is a bug and I should report it?

Comment: @dnakhain Have you found any workaround for this? I am too facing the similar issue.

Comment: No, sorry, but they solved the bug! We only have to wait them to push them to official channel.

Comment: @dnakhain Do you know something about this fix ? I have the same behavior on a Huawei Y5 2019 device with EMUI 9.0.1.183 (Android 9) and the Phone has the latest version available under "Software update". Thank you!

Comment: No news, sorry, the bug was marked as fix in their bug tracker but I've been following updates in my device and it wasn't included yet (Nokia 7.1 with Android 9).

Comment: As Phil said in the other comment, the fix is already applied in Android Q and there is a workaround using FLAG_RETRIEVE_INTERACTIVE_WINDOWS in Android P.