# onAccessibilityEvent not called on android pie

Tags: android, accessibilityservice

`onAccessibilityEvent` never calls on Android Pie.
First, this is my code

```
public class MyAccessibilityService extends AccessibilityService  {

    @Override
    public void onInterrupt() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent event) {
        final int eventType = event.getEventType();
        switch(eventType) {
            case AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_TEXT_CHANGED:
                Log.e("called called ","nnnnnnnnnnnnnnn TYPE_VIEW_TEXT_CHANGED "+visibility);
                show();
                break;
            case AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_FOCUSED:
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onServiceConnected() {
        super.onServiceConnected();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

and this is my manifest service

```
<service
    android:name=".service.MyAccessibilityService"
    class=".MyAccessibilityService"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:exported="false"
    android:permission="android.permission.BIND_ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityService" />
    </intent-filter>

    <meta-data
        android:name="android.accessibilityservice"
        android:resource="@xml/serviceconfig" />
</service>
```

and serviceConfig xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<accessibility-service xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:description="@string/app_name"
    android:accessibilityEventTypes="typeViewTextChanged|typeViewFocused"
    android:accessibilityFeedbackType="feedbackAllMask"
    android:notificationTimeout="20"
    android:canRetrieveWindowContent="true"
/>
```

`onServiceConnected`is getting called without a problem and `onDestroy` is never getting called, hence, my service is never getting killed. `onAccessibilityEvent` is not being called, but when I test it on older version like `4.4.4`
and `7.0` it works. However, on Pie `onAccessibilityEvent` never gets called

Comment: Hi Mitch, do you have any update about this issue ?, I'm facing the same behavior under Android 9 Pie on a Huawei Y5 2019 device. My Accessibility service is working fine on Android 4, 7 and 8.

Comment: @daily tube Were you able solve this problem?

Comment: @Rektirino still have same problem till now

Comment: @dailytube Try this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53290729/was-accessibilityservice-changed-in-android-pie

Answer (score 0):

One thing to try is to remove the notificationTimeout. That parameter isn't well-tested.